# Java - MySql : Query to get all the values of the column

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
SELECT col_name1, col_name2, col_name3 from Table_Name;
```

I am using above SQL query and I have to get all the values in col_name3 which has more than 5 value.

I am using :

```
while(rs.next()){
    String value1 = rs.getString("col_name3");
    String value2 = rs.getString("col_name3");
}
```

But all value in the String value1 and value2 is the last value of the col_name3. Why?

Comment: You are getting `col_name3` for `value1` and `value2` in the while loop.
Out of `While` loop, you get last row value stored in `value1` and `value2`. As @Mike mentioned, you need array list for out of loop Operations!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get only the result of one columns then you can use a `List<String>`

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

while(rs.next()){
   list.add(rs.getString("col_name3"));
}
```

If you want to get all your columns then you need to change the type of your list to your Object :

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

while(rs.next()){
   list.add(new MyObject(rs.getString("col_name1"), rs.getString("col_name2"), rs.getString("col_name3")));
}
```

You can create a class that contain all the columns of your Object for example :

```
Class MyObject{
   private String col1;
   private String col2;
   private String col3;

   //Constructor
   public MyObject(String col1, String col2, String col3){
      this.col1 = col1;
      this.col2 = col2;       
      this.col3 = col3
   }

   //getter and setters
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to show your information you have two ways first like @Mick Mnemonic said in comment `override toString()` in your class MyObject like this :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MyObject{" + "col1=" + col1 + ", col2=" + col2 + ", col3=" + col3 + '}';
}
```

and your loop should look like this :

```
for(int i = 0; i<list.size; i++){
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Or you can get element by element :

```
for(int i = 0; i<list.size; i++){
    System.out.println(list.get(i).getCol1() + " " + list.get(i).getCol2());
}
```

Comment: while iterating by System.out.println(list.get(i)); i am gettin this wrong output:
com.yoga.studentsmark.MyObject@41d47b2b
com.yoga.studentsmark.MyObject@41d47b2b
com.yoga.studentsmark.MyObject@64e265d0
com.yoga.studentsmark.MyObject@64e265d0
com.yoga.studentsmark.MyObject@4b8a6e6e
com.yoga.studentsmark.MyObject@4b8a6e6e
com.yoga.studentsmark.MyObject@6d581e80
com.yoga.studentsmark.MyObject@6d581e80
com.yoga.studentsmark.MyObject@343a9d95
com.yoga.studentsmark.MyObject@343a9d95

Comment: You would need to override `toString()` in `MyObject` to return a concatenated list of all the column values.

Comment: yes like @MickMnemonic said or you can get column by column like this for example `System.out.println(list.get(i).getCol1()); `

Comment: @balan don't forgot to accept the answer please if it's solved your problem :)

Comment: its done sucessfully its working .i am sry i am new to stack flow how to accept the answer

Comment: thank you i am trying to ask a new question the question box shows error asking ctl+k but still it is not allowing me to post the question help to solve it

Comment: can you try to click to this link it will take you to ask question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 2):

This problem is because if you need to store all of the data you can't do it with only a 'String' object but with a Collection maybe so you will do:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
while(rs.next()){
    String value=rs.getString("col_name3");
    list.add(value);
}
```

Because as are you doing you store every time a new String in value1 and value2, overwriting the previous values so you will get only the last one.

With using a Collection you can dynamically store 'String' that you get in 'ResultSet' and save them all.

Then to operate on them you can use a forEach like this:

```
for(String value : list){
    System.out.prinln(value);
}
```

This will show in console every value in 'list'.

Answer (score 1):

because every time you overwrite previous value. Try using a List:

```
List<string> myValues=new List<string>();
while(rs.next()){
    myValues.Add(rs.getString("col_name3"));   
}
```